# when I try to output the final version of my document as pdf, my cool new Google (or other) TrueType font changes weight

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, fonts, adobe-acrobat, publishing

I love how many fonts are available for free from Google and other places, as well as from subscriptions like your Adobe plan.

When I finished a document recently with a popular TrueType font from Google, in my case Newsreader,
I tried to save it as pdf and there was a glaring shift in format that I have not dealt with before.

I rarely use serif fonts, but I liked the thin, ExtraLight version of Newsreader for my document title.
**But when I produce the pdf, that title instead looks Bold!**

I have tried all the fixes for making sure my font is Embedded, for using the different ways to create a pdf from a pdf printer or from "save as" or from "export" or from an Acrobat plugin . . .
. . . nothing helps!

## What gives with the font weight getting lost saving to pdf?

This project was with
~ Word 365
~ Windows 11
~ Newsreader-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf

Answer (score 1):

## Finally, right at the end of the story, we get to the important part that it is a "Variable" font

Variable fonts are an interesting newer packaging convenience.
They give a collection of, typically, font weights and stylings like italic in a single font file.

Operating systems like Windows know how to serve these appropriately to programs like Office and Adobe tools, which know how to use them inside the program.
When you use Word, you get the different weights and such as different font options,
and you use them as you like throughout your creation.

### The problem is that, for some reason today (fall 2023), the pdf creation tools are lagging in being able to implement the separate fonts in the Variable font package.

I don't have an explanation for why that is.
All the ways to convert to pdf that I tried seem to land on the "Regular" weight for the font.

### The usually easy fix is to shift to what is now called a "Static" font rather than the "Variable" font collection

- For Google Fonts, look for a folder named Static in your download zip
- For other sources, you have to similarly look for separate versions;  search for "Static"
- Probably delete the Variable font on your computer
- Install one or more of the Static files
- Re-select the font for the desired text in your document or other creation *

---

* ok, be aware that last step could be a pain depending on how you and your tool implement fonts, but this does work

Comment: can you tell me more about that ?   How are Variable fonts and output to pdf connected to HTML?